# Why are these particles used here?

Tags: grammar, usage, particles, particle-に, particle-を

The following sentence is from [a blog called Nippon Talk](http://www.nippontalk.com/en/hot-water-washing-machines-%E6%B8%A9%E6%B0%B4%E6%B4%97%E6%BF%AF%E6%A9%9F/):

> お湯{ゆ}を使{つか}える洗濯機{せんたくき}のパワーに感動{かんどう}した夫{おっと}は、沖縄{おきなわ}旅行{りょこう}から帰{かえ}るとすぐにその洗濯機{せんたくき}についての情報{じょうほう}を調{しら}べ始{はじ}めた。

I'm trying to pick apart the words in an effort to understand Japanese grammar.

Here's the first part:

> お湯{ゆ}を使{つか}える洗濯機{せんたくき}のパワーに感動{かんどう}した夫{おっと}は、・・・
>   Oyu o tsukaeru sentakuki no pawaa ni kandoushita otto wa...

I translated this as:

> お湯を使える洗濯機
>   Oyu o tsukaeru sentakuki
>   *'washing machine that uses hot water'*

and

> ・・・のパワーに感動した夫は
>   …no pawaa ni kandoushita otto wa
>   *'husband that is excited by the power of washing machine that uses hot water'*

Why are the particles を (o) and に (ni) used in the way that they are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did a good job translating these sentences!

を marks the object for the verb 使える. What can be used by the wash mashine? Hot water.

に is here a bit more tricky and indicates a reason, why he gets excited. Two humorous examples (from the anime AcchiKocchi) with this "reason"-usage:

**[寒]{さむ}さに[震]{ふる}える**つみきさんを籠に乗せて早く暖かい地へ (つみきさん is shivering, because of cold.)

---

さっきの**先生には[驚]{おどろ}いた**な。**あまりの[白]{しろ}さに** (I was surprised, because of our teacher. Because of all the white)

どういう意味だ？ (What do you mean?)

先生の下着白だったようじゃな (Her underwear was white, wasn't it?)

Comment: Thank you very much. So basically it means that the power of the hot-water washing machine was the reason that he got excited?

Comment: Exactly! You might also want to read a good overall description about the に particle: http://www.imabi.net/l24theparticleni.htm . He says "に shows deep establishment of an action or state. It is for the most part equivalent to "at". ", which works quite well for your sentence: He got surprised at the power...